# z-range threshold for matrix heat map in Gnuplot

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

Background: 
I have a cross-correlation matrix of rows *i* and columns *j* with only z values ranging between -1 and 1. I'm able to output a nice heat map using the following script:

```
unset key
set tic scale 1
set xtics out
set ytics out
set palette defined (-1 "red", 0 "white", 1 "blue")
set cbrange [-1:1]
set cblabel "Correlation Function"
unset cbtics
set size ratio 1
set xrange [0:588]
set yrange [0:588]
set view map
splot 'file.dat' matrix with image
```

The Problem:
I want to 'screen out' certain z values, such that -0.50 ≤ z ≤ 0.50 are not taken into account for plotting.

Comment: What should happen to those values? They cannot disappear ;) If you want this whole range to be white, change your palette definition, otherwise explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Had a think about this some more, and took onboard the advice offered by Christoph. To achieve what I wanted I changed line from:

`set palette defined (-1 "red", 0 "white", 1 "blue")`

...to:

`set palette defined (-1 "red", -0.5, "white", 0.5 "white", 1 "blue")`

Worked like a charm.